# C# generic constraint: Array of Structs

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, value-type, generic-constraints

I would like to create a generic constraint that contains the type to be an array of value types (structs), something like:

```
public class X<T> where T : struct[]
```

or maybe

```
public class X<T, U>
    where U : struct
    where T : U[]
```

but this doesn't work. It seems System.Array cannot be used as type constraint.

So - how do I constrain a generic parameter to be an array of structs?

Updated after first answer:

```
public interface IDeepCopyable<T>
{
    T DeepCopy(T t);
}


public class DeepCopyArrayOfValueTypes<T> : IDeepCopyable<T>
    where T : is an array of value types
{
    T Copy(T t) {...}
}
```

Comment: Had that been possible, the elements in the array would have no compile-time type.

Comment: That should be `IDeepCopyable<T> where T : IDeepCopyable<T>`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need to.

Just constrain it to  `: struct`, then write `T[]` instead of `T` when using the type parameter.

```
public class DeepCopyArrayOfValueTypes<T> : IDeepCopyable<T[]>
    where T : struct
{
    public T[] DeepCopy(T[] t) {...}
}
```

Comment: Note that this constrains you to an array of *non nullable* structs.

Comment: @Eric The opposite unfortunately isn't supported in C#. (in CIL it's `.ctor ([mscorlib]System.ValueType)`)

Comment: Nice solution. It works for classes. If only there was one for constraining in methods...